# Ways and tricks to secure website / make it private?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, security, apache2

I am soon launching a website but I want it to be secured / private for testing. It is on its real domain now; I already added a htaccess authentication (with htpasswd). I'm on apache2 / Ubuntu 16.04

I thought of using `a2dissite` whenever I'm done working on it at the end of the day, so that it's not even possible to reach the domain / display the page.

I enabled these in my apache2 config file:

```
ServerTokens Prod
ServerSignature Off 
TraceEnable off
```

and :

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
    Options -Indexes
</Directory>
```

What other things can be done to enhance security and even making the site totally private ?

edit - I had required authentification via htaccess + htpasswd also, I forgot to say, it was done first.

Comment: Require authentication?

Comment: @larsks oh yea that I did too forgot to say, probably the first thing I did. Require authentification via htaccess + htpasswd , thanks

Comment: See Apache's [Access Control](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html), [Module mod_authz_core](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html), [Module mod_authz_host](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_host.html), etc. There are many possibilities.

Comment: @mivk I did not know these, I always limited myself to only the basics so far. Awesome, great resources there thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't `a2dissite` as it would make the default `VirtualHost` to replace your domain name that is already pointed to the server in DNS, possibly affecting your SEO. In addition to the *HTTP basic authentication*:

- You could restrict the access to the IP addresses or blocks that are used for building the site.
- I would also force TLS with HSTS even during the development.

E.g.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    Redirect permanent / https://example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem

    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains"
    </IfModule>

    <Location />
        <RequireAny>
            Require ip 192.0.2.100
            Require ip 198.51.100.0/24
        </RequireAny>
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thank you for this great answer full of information. I will look deeper in the TLS / HSTS  to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

Of the many ways to limit access, here is an example which allows any of

- Authenticated users who are members of the "my_valid_group" group
- OR [from localhost](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_host.html#reqlocal) : client IP 127.0.0.0/8 or ::1 or same IP as server
- OR from a specific host name (like a dynamic DNS host), without the need for a matching reverse lookup, as described under [`forward-dns`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_host.html#reqfwddns)

```bsh
<Location />
  AuthType      Basic
  AuthName      "This requires user name and password"
  AuthUserFile  /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
  AuthGroupFile /etc/apache2/.htgroup

  # <RequireAny> # this is not needed: it's the default

  # users listed in AuthUserFile + in the group in AuthGroupFile
  Require group my_valid_group                   

  Require local                                  

  Require forward-dns myhost.dynamic.example.com

  # </RequireAny>
</Location>
```

Other possibilities:

- [`Require ip ...`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_host.html#reqip) as in Esa Jokinen's answer
- [`Require host example.com`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_host.html#reqhost) : "Only if the forward and reverse DNS are consistent and the hostname matches [the end of the string] will access be allowed."
- [`Require env ...`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html#reqenv) : Check an Environment variable previously set with `SetEnv` or [`SetEnvIf`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_setenvif.html#setenvif)
- etc.

Answer (score 0):

use **netsparker** to test some basics stuff, or you could just hire a pentester (more expensive).
But there's free bug bounties programs, you can just put your website there and let pentesters report vulnerablities. (I think it's bit risky cause you don't know who will see you program. An ethical hacker or just a kid trying to harm your system).

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for this reference. I am going to look at netsparker. Yea I don't think I'll risk the free alternatives, don't really trust these , you are right.